# What kind of damping is this $F = -ax|x'|$?

Tags: forces, friction, terminology, non-linear-systems, dissipation

From Applied Mathematics by Logan:

> A mass hanging on a spring is <...> governed by
>   $$mx'' = -ax|x'| - kx$$
>   where $-ax|x'|$ is a nonlinear damping force.

I looked up "nonlinear damping" and found $F=-a|x'|^px'$ which is clear enough.

As far as I know one thinks of $F= -ax'$ damping as of viscous drag.

What is the interpretation of $F = -ax|x'|$ damping?

It confuses me that it has $x$ in it. Why would the damping force care whether the mass is above or below the origin? Shouldn't the damping force depend solely on the velocity of the mass?

Comment: @Qmechanic: As far as I can see, quadratic drag is $F=- a\dot{x}^2$. What am I missing?

Comment: This damping is interesting. It has negative damping when x is negative but positive damping when x is positive.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at this in a slightly different way. Rearranging it:

$$ m \ddot{x} = -(a|\dot{x}|+k) x = -k_{eff} x$$

If you look at it that way, it is really a variable, non-linear stiffness $k_{eff}$ that depends on the velocity, rather than a damping that depends on the position. In this respect (assuming $a > 0$), the stiffness coefficient has a lower bound of $k$ and the maximum depends on the maximum velocity. Given a periodic-type motion, at least initially, the stiffness would be $k$ at $\pm x_{max}$ and the stiffness would be a maximum when it was near $x = 0$, where velocity is a maximum.

Given all of that, I cannot think of exactly what kind of physical scenario this would represent off the top of my head. But one could imagine it is a mass oscillating somehow in a non-Newtonian fluid. I suppose it would be a shear-thickening fluid where viscosity is zero when the body is not moving and viscosity is a maximum when the body is moving fastest.

Displacement-dependent dampers seem to have applications in automotive and aircraft suspensions -- see [this paper and references at the end of the introduction](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Shahab_Ilbeigi/publication/257633767_A_novel_scheme_for_nonlinear_displacement-dependent_dampers/links/553fe7fd0cf2320416ece9a2.pdf). It would appear that hydraulic systems pushing/pulling fluid through an orifice may be modeled this way, as well as tapered pistons and a few other things.